# Update slider in swiftUI when application returns in foreground

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
@ObservedObject var playerObservedObject: PlayerFrameWork
```

`Slider(value: self.$playerObservedObject.displayTime, in: (0...self.playerObservedObject.itemDuration), onEditingChanged: {`

So when I jump into background & returning on foreground slider is not updating however I already used `ObservedObject`

Comment: Do you update the variable when the app is in the background?

Comment: If it doesn't automatically update, try using the `UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification` to manually update when the application enters foreground.